# Regular text with data binding displays just plaintext in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

If I use `<Label text="Welcome {{ username }}" />` no username appears.

Literally "Welcome {{ username }}" is visible - plaintext appears.

However using just `<Label text="{{ username }}" />` works as intended, the username is passed.

I can work with this but am wondering if this is normal and if I'm doing it wrong.

*Using plain JS with NativeScript, not angular or typescript.*

[image: Code side by side in same page]

Comment: Usually, NativeScript likes to have explicit closing tags, not `<Label />`.

Comment: Hmm I just tried this and it's still not passing the var. (used closing </Label>)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I wasn't providing an answer to your question, just a comment on your syntax. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I would tend towards `[text]="'Welcome ' + username"` myself, anyway.

Comment: No problem. I'll just edit my code behind file with "welcome" like you said. This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work: 
`<Label text="Welcome {{ username }}" />`

It should be: `<Label text="{{ 'Welcome ' + username }}" />`